# Modify libusb to accept file descriptor

Tags: android, android-ndk, usb, libusb, libusb-1.0

I modified libusb1.0 open function as follows:

```
static int op_open2(struct libusb_device_handle *handle, int fd) {
    struct linux_device_handle_priv *hpriv = _device_handle_priv(handle);

    hpriv->fd = fd;

    return usbi_add_pollfd(HANDLE_CTX(handle), hpriv->fd, POLLOUT);
}
```

where fd was obtained via [android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection.html#getFileDescriptor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getFileDescriptor%28%29)

```
final UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device); 
return connection.getFileDescriptor();
```

Unfortunatelly I keep getting an error when I call

```
static int op_claim_interface(struct libusb_device_handle *handle, int iface)
{
    int fd = _device_handle_priv(handle)->fd;

    int r = ioctl(fd, IOCTL_USBFS_CLAIMINTF, &iface);

    if (r) {
        if (errno == ENOENT)
            return LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND;
        else if (errno == EBUSY)
            return LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY;
        else if (errno == ENODEV)
            return LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE;

        usbi_err(HANDLE_CTX(handle),
            "claim interface failed, error %d errno %d", r, errno);
        return LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**claim interface failed, error -1 errno 9**

which is translated to "Bad file number". The file descriptor I get from Java is a positive integer!

The only other small detail is that my native code runs as a separate binary that is spawned with a Java ProcessBuilder. But they share the same uid, so I presume the USB permissions I have from Java should still apply for libusb.

I don't need to be platform independent, so any hacks would do the job :)

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Additional information! The output I get from **lsof** is (shortened to stress the most interesting part of it)

```
my.activity 13374     u0_a62  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /system/bin/app_process
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    0       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/null
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    1       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/null
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    2       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/null
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    3       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/log/main
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    4       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/log/radio
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    5       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/log/events
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    6       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/log/system
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    7       ???                ???       ???        ??? /system/framework/core.jar
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    8       ???                ???       ???        ??? /system/framework/core-junit.jar
my.activity 13374     u0_a62    9       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/__properties__ (deleted)
...
my.activity 13374     u0_a62   44       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/bus/usb/002/002
...    
my.activity 13374     u0_a62   51       ???                ???       ???        ??? pipe:[51015]
my.activity 13374     u0_a62   53       ???                ???       ???        ??? pipe:[51016]
...

my_exe   13546     u0_a62  exe       ???                ???       ???        ??? /data/data/my.activity/files/my_exe
my_exe   13546     u0_a62    0       ???                ???       ???        ??? pipe:[51015]
my_exe   13546     u0_a62    1       ???                ???       ???        ??? pipe:[51016]
my_exe   13546     u0_a62    2       ???                ???       ???        ??? pipe:[51016]
my_exe   13546     u0_a62    3       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/log/main
my_exe   13546     u0_a62    4       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/log/radio
my_exe   13546     u0_a62    5       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/log/events
my_exe   13546     u0_a62    6       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/log/system
my_exe   13546     u0_a62    9       ???                ???       ???        ??? /dev/__properties__ (deleted)
my_exe   13546     u0_a62  mem       ???              b3:09         0     302530 /data/data/my.activity/files/my_exe
my_exe   13546     u0_a62  mem       ???              b3:09     36864     302530 /data/data/my.activity/files/my_exe
my_exe   13546     u0_a62  mem       ???              b3:09     40960     302530 /data/data/my.activity/files/my_exe
my_exe   13546     u0_a62  mem       ???              b3:03         0        200 /system/bin/linker
my_exe   13546     u0_a62  mem       ???              b3:03     57344        200 /system/bin/linker
my_exe   13546     u0_a62  mem       ???              b3:03     61440        200 /system/bin/linker
```

Which makes me think that the file descriptor 44 that I pass to my_exe is actually not inherited!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that the file descriptor was not inherited by the process. If one uses JNI everything should be fine, but if you want to interface with a third party application, you would need to transfer the file descriptor to the third party application.

My solution was to [use UNIX sockets](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch17lev1sec4.html) to transfer the fd via JNI and it worked!

P.S.

I released the project under the GNU license - https://github.com/martinmarinov/rtl_tcp_andro-

Comment: i use UNIX sockets to pass file descriptor, but unfortunately i'm getting LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY all the time. fd is positive so it seems to be good. in android app i just open the device and don't claim interface. i'm sure to open the right device as i search for it using pid/vid. what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

File handles are private to a process. Passing them to a different process as-is is guaranteed to not work on any flavor of *nix.

Android's Binder/Parcel IPC interface can marshal file descriptors.

Or you can have the handle inherited - if it's already open when the process is spawned, the handle will be valid in the spawned process as well.

Comment: Yes, the handler is first obtained and then the process is spawned. Is there any way I can tell the system "give me the handler I already have for file x" or "give me a list of all of the handlers my process has opened"

Comment: I discovered lsof, see my updated question for output from it